# Jerky movement of button when view is loaded

Tags: android

My view is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/self_destruct"
        android:onClick="selfDestruct" />

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

My manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.nicobeta.camerabeta" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PreviewLibrary"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_preview_library" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".postProcessing"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_post_processing" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

and my styles.xml file is:

```
<resources>
<color name="white_opaque">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="pitch_black">#FF000000</color>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white_opaque</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

I've tried to remove the title bar, as you can see above.  However, when I load the view via:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("postProcessing","Post Processing Started");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_processing);
    }
```

I get a jerky motion.  First the button is located above the view and is partially not visible, then the button is quickly moved downwards so that it fits on the screen.  How do I get rid of this jerking motion?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height of webview to wrap content as below

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
        />
```

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately.  I get the same behavior if I remove the webview entirely.  The behavior may be caused by my previous efforts to remove the title bar.